# What is the difference between server side event and Web hook [Reverse API]?

Tags: webhooks, server-side

What is the difference between **[Server side events SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)** and **[Web hook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7uENSm-w1g)**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is:

1) using **SSE** you pull updates to your **Front-End**.

2) using **Web-hook** you pull updates to your **Back-End**.

The first is simplier, easier to implement and manage.
The second is more secure/reliable.

Also, some server may implement long-polling, which will delay response until new data arrives, so it might be used instead of SSE.